# Check for abbreviations in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

how can the abbreviations behind words be identified and counted most efficiently and entered into a new column, but only if they are correct.

Desired output:

```
|-------Name---------------------------||-Count-|
This is Ante Meridian (AM) not included||   3   |         
This is Ante Meridian (AM)     included||   3   |     
This is Ante Meridian (AM) not included||   3   |     
Extra module with Post Meridian (PM)   ||   1   |     
Post Meridian (PO) is not available    ||   0   |  #Mismatch
```

Comment: Can you be more detailed and specific? How are you identifying abbreviations?

Comment: (AM) occurs 3 times, (PM) 1 time and (PO) is not the an abbreviation of the leading word "Post Meridian".

Comment: It's not really clear what your doing here. So are there strings in your data frame that contain abbreviations? Or are you wanting to create abbreviations for certain words? If you post a sample of your data frame it may be easier to help.

Comment: are the words always in brackets?

Comment: They are already in the dataframe as the example shows. I just want to count correct abbreviations in each sentence. @Datanovice, no. Some sentences have no abbreviations.

Comment: Do you already have an algorithm/code to identify the abbreviations?

Comment: Not really, thats why I ended up here with this question.

Comment: are the abbreviations always upper case?

Comment: Yes, if there are any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to use regex to figure out if the letters in the () match the two words before it.

```
#get two words before (
wordsbefore = df['Name'].str.extract(r'(\w+) (\w+) (?=\()')

#get first letter of both words and make it what it should be in ()
check = wordsbefore[0].str.extract(r'(^.)') + wordsbefore[1].str.extract(r'(^.)')

#check if letters in () matches our check
df['count'] = np.where(df['Name'].str.extract(r"\((.*)\)") == check, df['Name'].str.extract(r"\((.*)\)"), 0)
```

Now you have a df where the acynoym is in its own column, and if it doesnt match, its 0. Now we just need to replace with the count.

```
df['count'] = df['count'].map(dict(df[df['count']!=0]['count'].value_counts())).fillna(0)

              Name                          count
0   This is Ante Meridian (AM) not included   3.0
1   This is Ante Meridian (AM) included       3.0
2   This is Ante Meridian (AM) not included   3.0
3   Extra module with Post Meridian (PM)      1.0
4   Post Meridian (PO) is not available       0.0
```

If a line does not have a () in it you will end up also with 0.

---

For 3 and adjustable for more if you just follow the pattern in the loop:

```
acy = re.compile("\((.*)\)")
twoWords = re.compile('(\w+) (\w+) (?=\()')
threeWords = re.compile('(\w+) (\w+) (\w+) (?=\()')
firstLet = re.compile('(^.)')

acyList = []

#Pull the first letters out of the words before ()
for index, value in df['Name'].iteritems():
    #get letters in () two inspect to check if we need to check 2 or 3 words
    getAcy = acy.search(value)
    try:    
        #check if length of letters in () is 2
        if len(getAcy[1]) == 2:
            #search for two words
            words = twoWords.search(value)
            #get first letter of two words before () and add phrase to list
            acyList.append(firstLet.search(words[1])[1] + firstLet.search(words[2])[1])

        #check if length of letters in () is 3
        elif len(getAcy[1]) == 3:
            #search for three words
            words = threeWords.search(value)
            #get first letter of three words before () and add phrase to list
            acyList.append(firstLet.search(words[1])[1] + firstLet.search(words[2])[1] + firstLet.search(words[3])[1])

    except:
        acyList.append(np.NaN)

df['count'] = np.where(df['Name'].str.extract(r"\((.*)\)") == pd.DataFrame(acyList), df['Name'].str.extract(r"\((.*)\)"), 0)
df['count'] = df['count'].map(dict(df[df['count']!=0]['count'].value_counts())).fillna(0)
```

Comment: he said all abbreviations aren't always brackets in comments, I was thinking the only way to do this is to regex any upper case words with len > 2 and see that matches the any combination of any word in the sentence.. will be expensive computationally speaking.

Comment: ahh, I thought he meant that there was no abbreviations at all in the sentence.

Comment: Ben is right. No abbreviation at all sentences. Your solution looks good. However, what happens if there is a sentence with three instead of two words?

Comment: @EchoCache as in there are 3 letters instead of 2 in the ()? Then it would just fail to match, and be 0 at the moment.

Comment: So a dynamical way for n letters is not possible I guess?

Comment: Its significantly more difficult

Comment: @EchoCache See my edit for 3, it can be used for more as long as you adjust it correctly, but it shouldnt be too difficult to do.

Comment: That's right. Your solution works so far. But what happens if we have two abbreviations in one sentence, smth like: Post Meridian (PM) and Ante Meridian (AM) then the acyList get nan values. ````ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects````